# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - jobs command not working

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-10.04, shell, process, command-line

When I used to execute the jobs command I got a list of running processes with their respective process-ID, but in Ubuntu lucid lynx this doesn't seem to be working. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Try `sleep 15 & jobs -l` and you should see an entry listed for the sleep command running in the background. After 15 seconds issue another `jobs -l` and it will be gone (at some point after pressing enter at the prompt you'll get a "Done" message).

Answer (score 1):

`jobs` displays the status of jobs in the current session (ie. those launched from the terminal you are currently in) only. To get a list of all running processes, try `ps -e`.

If what you want is `jobs` but make it output PIDs, run `jobs -l`.

Comment: jobs -l doesn't seem to be working. ps -e does generate output

Comment: if jobs -l doesn't do anything, that means you have no process currently running in the terminal where you are typing jobs -l. What exactly is the behavior you want?